# Excluding unused libraries from binary

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin, compiler-optimization

So I'm trying to achieve the following setup. 
I have an iOS app written with Xamarin.iOS and I've made a build script that builds the app for different configs. I have a dev, qa and prod. In dev, I have some libraries that need to be included like HockeyApp sdk for logging which should be excluded from the binary when building for QA and Prod to reduce the binary size. I know I can use **ConditionalAttribute** to exclude unwanted codes for QA and PROD configs but how do I remove the unused library ? Is there any optimization that I can use for this situation ?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude HockeyApp SDK from your production build? Especially in production it helps a lot to detect your apps crashes.

Comment: Now that you suggest it, I'm thinking about it but I know for some configs we want to use Flurry instead and it conflicts with Hockey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ifdefs to exclude code using those libraries from your app.

Libraries that are not used in code will not end up in the final app.

Comment: I tried it but I still see Hockey apps *.dll in the package.

Comment: Please add -v -v -v -v to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options, rebuild, and pastebin the full build output.